# Android , What is the difference between these codes?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i was watching thenewboston's tutorial about fragments and i came across this line of code..

```
    @Override
    public void sendtex(String top, String bottom) {


      BottomFregment_class bottomFregment = (BottomFregment_class) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Main);
      bottomFregment.finale(top,bottom);
    }
```

this was to change TextView by getting text from another fragment! and "sendtext is implemented method from that fragment"

i replaced

```
BottomFregment_class bottomFregment = (BottomFregment_class) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.Main);
      bottomFregment.finale(top,bottom);
```

with

```
 BottomFregment_class bottomFregmentClass = new BottomFregment_class();
    bottomFregmentClass.finale(top,bottom);
```

and everything worked fine!

i want to know that is there any difference in between these two codes?
or will this cause any performance issues?

Comment: first case is getting reference for a declared fragment in the xml. but in 2nd case you are creating a new fragment and you have to bind it dynamically to any other parent.

Comment: The diffrence is that in original code existing fragment is retrieved with fragment manager help and in your case you are createing new fragment instance

Answer (score 2):

In the first, you fetch an existing fragment, maybe with some data in there, on the other one you create an empty one.